# Reference for Langlands functoriality conjecture view towards classical examples

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-program

I want to know if there's any good reference on Langlands functoriality conjecture which provides connection with classical examples. What I have in my mind are followings:

- Classical Rankin-Selberg (nice $L$-function $L(s, f\otimes g)$ built on two modular forms $f, g$) and general Rankin-Selberg $\mathrm{GL}_{n} \times \mathrm{GL}_{m} \to \mathrm{GL}_{nm}$
- Hecke and Maass's construction of modular/Maass forms from quadratic characters (real/imaginary quadratic fields over $\mathbb{Q}$) and automorphic induction
- Symmetric square lifting (this may corresponds to some construction of $\mathrm{GL}_{3}$ modular forms from classical modular forms, but I don't know anything about theory of $\mathrm{GL}_{3}$ automorphic forms/representations.)
- Doi-Naganuma lifting (from ordinary modular form to Hilbert modular form) and Base change
- Classical theta series and Howe duality stuff

Is there any good resource that contains explanation for these contents? (It would be great if there's sketches of proofs for general known cases and how the proofs for the classical version extend.)

Comment: I don't know if there is, sadly. I learnt these things essentially by osmosis. Some of the books that I slogged through included "An Introduction to the Langlands Program" by Bump et al, "Lectures on Automorphic $L$-Functions" by Cogdell, Kim, and Murty, and "Simple Algebras, Base Change, and the Advanced Theory of the Trace Formula" by Arthur and Clozel. None are particularly straightforward to read, however.

Comment: Oh, and for the symmetric square lift, you can't really do much better than the original: "A Relation between Automorphic Representations of GL(2) and GL(3)" by Gelbart and Jacquet. You'll need to be pretty comfortable with automorphic representations to read this though (at the level of Gelbart/Goldfeld-Hundley/Bump's books, say).

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thank you for your suggestion!